# Simple regular expression not working in expect

Tags: regex, expect

My `expect` script which is as simple as

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 60
spawn docker run -it ubuntu:19.04
expect {
  -re "root@[0-9]+:\/#"
}
send -- exit
expect eof
```

fails due to

```
$ expect script.expect
spawn docker run -it ubuntu:19.04
invalid command name "0-9"
    while executing
"0-9"
    invoked from within
"expect {
  -re "root@[0-9]+:\/#"
}"
    (file "script.expect" line 5)
```

I expect this to succeed because it's a valid Perl regular expression or to fail with a message explaining the error in the regular expression. It seems like `-re` is trying to do something else than matching the specified re which doesn't make any sense.

I tried escaping everything I could guess in the re with no change in the result.

I'm using expect 5.45.4 on Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: `expect` doesn't use Perl. (I think it uses TCL?) Anyway, it looks like it expects a POSIX regex, cause I had to switch to `\[0-9\]` to match `0`, `1`, etc

Comment: Expect, as a Tcl extension, would want a [Tcl regex](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expect is an extension of Tcl. Tcl uses square brackets for command substitution.

Additionally, Tcl is like shell in that it allows command and variable substitution within double quotes. Tcl's non-interpolating quotes are curly braces (similar to the shell's single quotes).

See https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

So, you want to enclose the regex in braces:

```tcl
expect -re {root@[0-9]+:/#}
```